# Tranferencia de arquivos em python, cliente-servidor

Tags: python, socket, cliente-servidor, tupla

Galera estou com um problema no meu código, preciso desenvolver uma aplicação que seja capaz de enviar um arquivo a um servidor e também conseguir recuperar arquivos do servidor
Estou usando uma tupla para enviar os dados ao servidor

```
nome = input('Digite o nome do arquivo a ser enviado: ')
arquivo = open(nome, 'r')
message = arquivo.read()
tupla = (opcao, message)

# Enviando ao servidor
socket_object.sendall(tupla)
```

Porém estou tendo este erro

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'
```

Existe alguma forma de transformar a tupla em bytes para envia-la através do socket?

PS: Estou usando o python3 padrão do terminal do ubuntu

Comment: Como é definido o objeto `socket_object`? Utiliza o pacote `socket` nativo do Python?

Comment: `socket_object = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)`

Comment: Primeiro, acredito que você não possa enviar uma tupla pelo socket, apenas uma string, então você pode convertê-la para JSON antes, por exemplo: `socket_object.sendall(str.encode(json.dumps(tupla)))`, ou algo semelhante.

Comment: Obtive um erro `NameError: name 'json' is not defined`, estou trabalhando com os terminais do ubuntu e com o python3 padrão dele

Comment: Você precisa incluir o pacote `import json`

Comment: Consegui envia-lo através do socket, porém nao consegui recupera-los no servidor, utilizei isso `data = socket_object.recv(1024)
        data = (str.decode(json.dumps()))`

Comment: E obtive este erro no servidor `OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected`

Comment: Consegui solucionar o erro `OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected`, o problema é para efetuar o decode, como poderia efetuar no lado do servidor para voltar a ser uma tupla?

Comment: Veja na resposta dada.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss desculpa, secalhar estavas a preparar-te para responder e "meti-me à frente", não reparei que estavas a falar aqui. Se achares que está menos correta eu retiro-a

Comment: @Miguel, sem problemas. Eu não havia respondido por não ter certeza se isso solucionaria o problema.

Comment: Pois @AndersonCarlosWoss acho que não resolveu, não foi suficiente lol. Ricardo deves ter a certeza que estás a excutar a função `recv` sob a socket certa, e que esta está conectada.

Comment: Obtive este erro: `tupla_recebida = json.loads(data.decode())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 7 (char 6)`

Comment: Ricardo, optei por tirar a resposta porque visto que para mandar dados em binário não pode ser dentro de um json. Mas estou a trabalhar para te ajudar na mesma

Comment: Tudo bem, sem problemas, valeu a ajuda @Miguel

Comment: Olha estou a criar a funcionalidade, diz-me uma coisa... O teu servidor é para multiplos clientes? Ou só um?

Comment: Apenas um cliente

Comment: Ricardo testa isto: https://pastebin.com/53GDpmCg. Está muito básico mas faz o suposto... Python3 . Ajusta no lado servidor o nome da pasta onde será gravado o ficheiro

Comment: O truque é mandares um json com as informações que queres (neste caso, o tamanho/nome do ficheiro), e só depois os bytes que compõem o ficheiro. E Informar o servidor que a mensagem json foi totalmente recebido, fazemos isto enviando um byte nulo no final da mensagem em json.... E só depois o servidor começa a receber os bytes do ficheiro

Answer (score 3):

Sugiro que para tranferência de estruturas de dados uses [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html) ou [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pickle.html), embora com json a serialização [possa ser mais rápida](https://konstantin.blog/2010/pickle-vs-json-which-is-faster/).

Dito isto, esta pergunta sem querer torna-se um pouco nabragente/desafiante.

A descrição do próprio erro fala no problema, ou seja, precisas de mandar bytes e não um tuple, e como não podes converter um `tuple` em bytes diretamente mas pode fazê-lo com strings, podes enviar um json (embora neste caso se torne mais trabalhoso e por isso não vou fazer isso, explico em baixo a razão).

No entanto ainda temos um problema, não podes enviar os bytes do ficheiro no json porque ocorrem problemas com a serialização ([lista dos tipos de dados que json entende](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders)), terias de enviar [duas mensagens em separado](https://pastebin.com/53GDpmCg), uma com a informação adjacente (nome, tamanho do ficheiro etc.., em forma de um dict por exemplo) e outra com os bytes que o compõem, e MUITO IMPORTANTE, terias de enviar uma flag (byte nulo por ex, `b'\x00'`) no final da primeira para indicar que esta chegou ao fim e que o servidor pode então começar a receber os dados binários do ficheiro.

Esta flag tem de existir porque TCP é um [*streaming protocol*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446491/tcp-stream-vs-udp-message) não há garantia alguma que o método `recv` (da lado servidor neste caso) recebeu exatamente o json com a informação antes, pode conter apenas uma parte do json ou pode incluir alguma da informação binária do ficheiro à mistura.

Aqui coloco um exemplo básico de upoload de ficheiros para o servidor com pickle, onde podemos converter uma estrutura de dados (objetos, dicionários, tuples, etc...) em um [*byte stream*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/216597/what-is-a-byte-stream-actually), assim, com pickle, podemos enviar logo os dados necessários "de uma só vez", por isso neste caso facilita bastante:

Cliente:

```
import socket, pickle

f = input('escreva o nome do ficheiro')
f_bin = open(f, 'rb').read()
info = {'name': f, 'file': f_bin, 'opcao': 1} # ajustar opcao para adequar ao teu codigo
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect(('', 9005))
    s.sendall(pickle.dumps(info))
```

Servidor:

```
import socket, threading, pickle, time

def run(conn):
    info_bin = b''
    st = time.time()
    while True:
        c = conn.recv(2048)
        if not c:
            break
        info_bin += c
        if time.time() - st >= 2: # opcional, informacao sobre o total ja carregado
            print('bytes downloaded:', len(info_bin))
            st = time.time()
    info = pickle.loads(info_bin)
    if info['file']:
        dest = 'files/{}'.format(info['name'])
        with open(dest, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(info['file'])
        print('success on receiving and saving {} for {}'.format(info['name'], conn.getpeername()))
        conn.close()

host, port = ('', 9005)
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind((host, port))
    sock.listen(5)
    while True:
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        print('conn', addr)
        threading.Thread(target=run, args=(conn,)).start()
```

Não testei com multiplos clientes mas em príncipio também funcionará.

Deves ter de ajustar a tua conecção e o sítio onde o servidor escreverá o ficheiro

Comment: Fiz isso aqui, porém obtive este erro `data = socket_object.recv(1024)
OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected`

Comment: Acho que teria de ver o teu código do nessa parte, tens algum sítio onde possas mostrar? O nome da socket no lado servidor é `socket_object`?

Comment: Estou tendo o mesmo problema com o decode @Miguel

Comment: Obtive este erro: `tupla_recebida = json.loads(data.decode())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 7 (char 6)`

Comment: Podes mostrar o código sff. Coloca-o aqui sff http://ideone.com/ . Tanto o lado cliente como o servidor

Comment: Servidor: http://ideone.com/DhFl35 Cliente: http://ideone.com/4sutJ1

Comment: @RicardoMendes mas nesse código que me mostraste não fazes uso disto que coloquei na resposta. Não podes colocar bytecode em json, https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders esses são os tipos de dados que podes colocar em uma json string. Na minha resposta não estou a usar json, mas podia, daria mais trabalho mas podia